# Changing the order of double integration

Tags: integration, analysis

The function is $\int_0^8 \int_{y^{1/3}}^2 \sqrt{x^4 + 1}dxdy$ and the prompt is to change the order of integral and evaluate it.

Plotting the graphs for the limits $$y^{\frac{1}{3}} < x < 2$$
$$0 < y < 8$$

[image: graphing the limits]

Using the graph we can identify, changing the order of the limits will give us

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{x^3} \sqrt{x^4 + 1}dydx$$

$$\int_0^2 x^3\sqrt{x^4 + 1}dx$$

By substitution, assuming $x^4 + 1 = t$
$$4x^3 dx = dt$$
$$= \frac{1}{4} \int \sqrt{t}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{(17)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right)$$

Is this the correct way to change the order?

Comment: Guessing that $0 < y < 6$ should be changed to $0 < y < 8$?

Answer (score 3):

Most of it looks good, but you lost it towards the end, probably due to some sloppy notation. The integral
$$\frac{1}{4}\int \sqrt{t}$$
should really be a *definite* integral if it evaluates to a number (instead of a family of functions). Also, it should have a differential $\mathrm{d}t$ at the end!

To get the bounds, you need to transform the bounds of $x$ into bounds of $t$. When $x = 0$, we have $t = 1$. When $x = 2$, $t = 17$. So, our integral comes down to
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_1^{17} \sqrt{t} ~ \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{6}\left(17^{3/2} - 1\right)$$

Comment: Just beat me :( +1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you changed your order of integration correctly. Good Job! However, your final result is wrong because you integrated incorrectly in the last steps: $$\int_{x=0}^{x=2}x^3\sqrt{x^4+1}dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_{{\color{red}{t=1}}}^{t=17}\sqrt{t}dt=\frac{1}{6}\left(17\sqrt{17}-1\right)$$
where you mistakenly treated the lower bound for your $t$ as $0$, but when $x=0$, then $t=x^4+1=0^4+1=1$.